# Tracking banner impressions on website

Tags: google-analytics, ads, banner, web-analytics, adbannerview

I am trying to sell advertising space on my website but to do this I need to know the amount of impressions each banner gets in the various parts of the webpage and blog.

I tried doing it just in PHP / Javascript but the bots and spiders kept creating impressions so that didn't work.

I then researched how I could do it in analytics and read about using Events. But that doesn't seem to be working properly. The banner is in the footer and in the past 24 hours it has received 106 event "pushes" but the site has received  almost 4000 page views. Something isn't right!

This is the code I am using to track these impressions:

```
<img onload="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Site Banners', 'Impression', 'Website Name']);" src="http://www.my-site.com/images/website-x.png" />
```

I've also heard that using this will make the site run slower which is not good as I'm having complaints the site is slow as it is!

Any ideas on how to get statistical data on impressions of banner? Thanks

Comment: where is that page view number from? Is that number also from Google Analytics, or is that from your server log?

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics is not the tools to do that. What you want is an ad server. A couple options bellow:

- [OpenX](http://www.openx.com/)
- [DFP Small business](http://www.google.com/doubleclick/publishers/small-business/)

These are 2 free tools that you can install yourself and manage your ad spaces in your website. I would go first with DFP Small business, it's free up to 90M ad impressions / month.

If you need more than that you can use a paid tool or install and manage yourself with OpenX.

Answer (score 0):

OpenX closed down their free version on 22nd March.

An alternative you could try other than DFP small business is Adzerk.

DFP is good, it's a little more complex, it assumes an element of sophistication that most publishers lack.

Comment: OpenX can't be closed down, it is open source. They also have an enterprise solution under the same name and that can be confusing. http://www.openx.com/publisher/open-source-ad-server