# Google Analytics Tracking banner and form

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, banner

I have 5 banners on my site. All these banners link to a contact page, with another parameter.
Based on the banner clicked, an item in a dropdown list (`<select>`) is set.

With Google Analytics I want to track:

- Number of times each button is clicked
- Number of users who submitted the form with the banner option they chose before

Can I, and if so, how can I implement this with Google Analytics?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tracking banner impressions on website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598281/tracking-banner-impressions-on-website)

Answer (score 0):

You might like to check this out, had it bookmarked:[banner-clicks-monitoring-using-google-analytics](http://www.warriorforum.com/programming-talk/347517-banner-clicks-monitoring-using-google-analytics.html)

you can use google's custom url to create a campaign, which you can then have 'custom' url parameters like `&selecteditem=` you could use php or javascript to find the values required with them you build your custom url+paramaters

Link: [Create Custom URL - Google](http://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037445?hl=en&ref_topic=1032998)

Possible JavaScript solution to find the selected dropdown item:
Use the `value` property of the `<select>` element. For example:

```
// Set dropdown    
document.getElementById('your_select_id').value = '2';

// Get dropdown  
var value = document.getElementById('your_select_id').value;

alert(value);
// you would need to add or remove + add the new parameter
// once it is found you could make this into a function and
// call it on the selection change event.
```

Or

You can go for a different approach where you let your Google tracking code do the work.
Add this to your links attributes, for the form post you would still need to find out the selected item with in the below.
for this you will need to have your "Event Tracking" enabled, This must be set in your "Profile".

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Link Sponsored', 'Clicked Sponsored']);"
```

Comment: Yeah this is part of my answer. I can build specific links for the banners. However, I also need to track the submition of the form (with the 5 specific options in it)

Comment: you can use google's custom url to create a campaign, which you can then have 'custom' url parameters like &selecteditem= you could use php or javascript to find the values required with them you build your custom url+paramaters