# How to track .gif and flash banners using google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm Using in page analytics option in google analytics to track my wordpress site. i can track  all my contents and links apart from .gif and flash banner.i can't understand how to track .gif and flash banners using google analytics.

Following is the code i'm using

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://web.boc.lk/">
<img src="http://www.news360.lk/stg/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/400-x-120.gif">
    </a>
```

If anyone know how to do this please help me

Answer (score 0):

In-Page analytics will just work for internal links. If this is an external link in-page analytics will not count those clicks.

If you want a tool that gives you a full heatmap of the website you can try [CrazyEgg](http://www.crazyegg.com/).

But if you have banners on your site you really should be using a AdManager to manage this banners. These tools also give you stats on impressions and clicks and usually provide a better figure. Checkout this other answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15606096/272031